# Files uploaded with php scripts are owned by apache on Directadmin

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, suexec, suphp

Uploaded files are owned by apache, I have DirectAdmin installed and also mod_suexec is loaded into Apache. So is there anyway to upload file with account owner under mod_php(php5_module)?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not completely clear. If I get it:

> So is there anyway to upload file with account owner under mod_php(php5_module)?

No. You can run Apache as a particular user, but then *all* scripts will run at them (including all PHP ones), which probably isn't what you want.

If you want to have PHP scripts run as their respective user, you'll need to use suPHP. mod_php simply wasn't designed for this.

Comment: Really Thanks, what about mod_ruid2?

Comment: Yes, that'll work, but you should know about the incompatibilities: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache3/ModRuid2